# how to simplify this constraint?

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, constraints, nonlinear-analysis, constraint-programming

is there any way to simplify a constraint like this:

$$A_{1}...A_{n}=0$$

each $A_{I}$ is a polynomial with degree 2 in $R^{n}$. this means that at least one of the $A_{I}$ is zero.

if the other side was not 0 I could get log of both side!

Comment: I know log does not work. because log(0) is -inf. I am asking about another way)

Comment: Do any example, say $(x^2+1)(2x^2+x-7)=1$ for $n=2$. Even with $1$, what would you gain with a logarithm? If you have $(x^2+1)(2x^2+x-7)=0$, what could be better than to say either $x^2=-1$ or $2x^2+x-7=0$?

Comment: $log(x^{2}+1)+log(2x^{2}+x-7)=0 $ is easier to handle in optimization solvers.